# Conditionally Color ZSH Prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt, zshrc

I am trying to color my prompt based on the return code of the previous command. I have the following:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%~$(git_prompt_info) %($?.%{fg_bold[cyan]%}.%{$fg_bold[red]%})»%{$reset_color%} '
```

Specifically I'm having trouble with the `%($?.%{fg_bold[cyan]%}.%{$fg_bold[red]%})` portion.

Unfortunately my prompt ends up looking like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

After fixing my typo I now have:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%~$(git_prompt_info) %($?.%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}.%{$fg_bold[red]%})»%{$reset_color%} '
```

My prompt now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `$` for the parameter expansion, and you *don't* precede the `?` with a dollar; it's a flag for the conditional, not a parameter reference.

```
%(?.%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}.%{$fg_bold[red]%})
  ^   ^
```

Comment: Haha yup just saw that added it back but still some weird behavior. I'll update the question

Comment: Perfect after that second fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to send the return code (when different than 0) to `kill -l` so that you can display the name of the error code.

This is what I use (for the prompt at the right side)

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
RPS1='%(?..%{$fg_bold[red]%}[%? $(kill -l $?)]%{${reset_color}%} )%T' # time
```

Comment: Definitely interesting and I'll think about it, but my preference is more subtlety in my prompt. Thanks for sharing though